# Start primary key from a value in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I need to set the value of my primary key to start from 1150, but I can't lose my DB data, I created a new migration and executed the following codes:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->startValue(1150)->change();
        });
    }
```

I tried to run too

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->from(1150)->change();
        });
    }
```

Even running these migrations, the table keeps inserting in the default value of ids, 5, 6, 7...

Comment: $table->id()->startingValue(1150);

Comment: Unsuccessfully :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196045/set-auto-increment-field-start-from-1000-in-migration-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Schema::table('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
   DB::update("ALTER TABLE tickets AUTO_INCREMENT = 1150;");
});
```